# Database schema design and foreign keys

Tags: database, database-design, architecture, database-schema

I'm confused what a schema should be implemented in a following case:

I have two core tables `user` and `company` and a set of 'inherited'(in terms of ORM) tables like `user_type_1`, `user_type2` that extend `user` table with an own unique set of fields. And the same for `company_type_1`, `company_type_2` tables that extend `company` table with an own unique set of fields.

Also I have a `address` table. Every User and Company in a system can have own address.

My initial idea was to add `address_id` FK to address(id) PK to root `user` and `company` tables. This way every User or Company in a system can be associated with own address.

My colleague proposed another database schema design where `user_id` and `company_id` FKs have to be added to `address` table.

I'm really confused with this proposal right now. Could you please explain or this design can take a place ?

Comment: How many addresses can each user / company have? How many users / companies can each address belong to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you add `address_id` to the `user` and `company` tables, you're adding functional dependencies `user_id -> address_id` and `company_id -> address_id`. This would mean that each user or company can be associated with a single address, but each address can potentially be associated with multiple users or companies (unless you add a constraint to prevent that).

Your colleague's proposal to add `user_id` and `company_id` to the `address` table adds functional dependencies `address_id -> user_id` and `address_id -> company_id` meaning each address can be associated with one user, one company or both, but each user or company can potentially be associated with multiple addresses (unless you add a constraint to prevent that).

Between the two options you listed, there's a third - separate tables for the associations, e.g. `user_addresses (user_id FK, address_id FK)` and `company_addresses (company_id FK, address_id FK)`. This can handle any cardinality (one-to-one/one-to-many/many-to-one/many-to-many) depending on the PK (`address_id`, `user_id/company_id` or both) and possible unique constraints.

Which design is correct depends on your requirements.

Comment: Thank you very much for this explanation!

Comment: @ reaanb (& @alexanoid)  Adding columns to tables does not cause FDs to hold. This answer seems to assume that the column is added without affecting the CKs. That's the same thing as assuming the column is functionally determined by the CKs. Hence under the assumption, the FDs hold. Remember, a table just holds the rows that make its predicate true. If entity:address happens to be many:many, so be it, in whatever table(s) the pair appears in. (Of course, such a design might be subject to unwanted FDs and/or JDs.) This answer doesn't yet have the problems characterized & justified properly.

Comment: @philipxy You are correct that I assumed that the CKs aren't affected. I also assumed that the user, company and address tables are and should stay in 3NF. The problem seemed reasonably clear to me, if not rigorously worded.